# How can I re-create a File System Wallet given a seed phrase (and passphrase)?

Tags: wallet, cli

If I have my 12 words (and passphrase) and I want to re-create the json file that represents the wallet, what are the steps to accomplish this?

**Edit:** The method I used to create the wallet is as follows:

`solana-keygen new --outfile test_wallet.json`

Comment: can you elaborate the source software that originally generated the seed phrase?  it makes a difference as to how you recover

Comment: @trent.sol - Thanks for having me clarify that. I am currently testing everything using either JSON RPC APIs and/or the various CLIs. I have edited my description above. Also, given the potential for ambiguity, it might be helpful to future visitors to include some background about why different wallets need different ways to recover. Just a thought... though that could get covered in a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@krishnna's answer is correct implicitly.  The explicit command would be more like:

```
solana-keygen recover --outfile recovered-wallet.json ASK
```

The pertinent part being the addition of the `ASK` positional parameter, which tells `solana-keygen recover` to use raw ed25519 keypair derivation rather than bip32-ed25519/slip0010 as would be used for a wallet originating from something like a hardware or web wallet.  The latter case is described [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/114/36) for those interested

Comment: Pending the typo fix per my edit, this answers exactly what I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To restore the wallet for a given mnemonic if you have CLI installed you can use solana-keygen

```
solana-keygen recover
```

To know more -
[Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase)

Answer (score 1):

Solana CLI also comes with a tool to 'recover' a wallet to a keypair with your mnemonic seed phrase.

```
solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=0/0' --outfile keypair.json
```

If you have multiple accounts in your Phantom wallet, you increment the first number after ?key=

For example, 0/0 will target the first wallet, 1/0 will target the second, and so on.