# Created a wallet through Solana CLI but given seed phrase points to different address

Tags: wallet

I created a new file wallet using:

```
solana-keygen new --outfile ./new_wallet.json
```

Output of this command shows a pubkey and a seed phrase to save. I tried to import this output seed phrase into a wallet extension. When I entered this seed phrase, it showed like 100+ accounts to import and none of them was actual pubkey of created wallet.
I confirmed it using:

```
solana-keygen pubkey ./new_wallet.json
```

The PublicKey output of this command, does not exist on seed phrase import. Then I tried importing wallet using private key, this works nicely. But seed phrase import points to completely different address. I am confused.

Comment: yeah, i'm also interested in this! I'm pretty sure it has to do with derivation paths and the CLI using a different one than the wallet extensions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I elaborated the differences between CLI and common web wallet key derivation in [this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/114/36)

Answer (score 1):

It is because of derivations. For example you can read in the Phantom docs:
https://docs.phantom.app/resources/faq#how-does-phantom-import-wallet-addresses

Send a small amount of Sol to the new wallet you just created and it will place it at the top of the list for importing.